# D-link dwm-156 modem gets detected on ubuntu 14.04LTS 64-bit but not get conected to internet

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, usb-modem, modem

I am a dedicated admirer of Ubuntu operating system. I have been using Ubuntu for a long time since Ubuntu 11.04. I have a D-link dwm-156 modem. It was easy to work with this modem on Ubuntu 11.10 .

It also worked great on Ubuntu 12.04 ,12.10, 13.04 and 13.10. There I needed to install `dlinkusbmodem.deb` that comes with it with some 32bit library to make it work on 64-bit Ubuntu. But now I have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64-bit from Ubuntu13.10 64-bit.

Ubuntu 14.04LTS detect my modem in network manager but when I click on it to connect, it doesn't get connected and led of my modem start blinking.

How to resolve this problem and how to make my modem which contain 32bit driver works great again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a way to connect my D-Link DWM-156 modem on Ubuntu14.04LTS 64-bit. The problem was this Modem has a 32-bit driver and network manager identify it but network manager is unable to connect. [Here's a link that will help you to enable dlink modem](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto/SetUpDialer)
. Actually I found a solution on **help.ubuntu.com/community/** 
           .It has suggested a way to enable modem using  **pppconfig & pon/poff** and I tried this and as expected it worked. Now my modem is enabled and its working. To make my modem work I need to use terminal to enter command like pon - to enable modem, poff- to disconnect or to disable modem and plog - to check log. Here's the steps that I used and I want to mention it clearly that It is mentioned on the website **help.ubuntu.com/community/** and so I am just copying it to here to help you.......

This is a command line based option to manage dialup connections. This makes it very flexible, but maybe not so straightforward to configure.

Collecting Information

You will need:

```
Your ISP's phone number
Your username and password on the ISP
The name of the modem device (/dev/...)
```

Setting up ppp

```
Open a terminal (Applications > System Tools > Terminal) and type

  $ sudo pppconfig

You will be on the main menu. Choose 'Create Create a connection'.
Leave the name as 'provider', hit 'Ok'.
Select 'Dynamic Use dynamic DNS', hit 'Ok'.
Select 'PAP Peer Authentication Protocol', hit 'Ok'.
Enter your user name for the ISP, hit 'Ok'.
Enter your password for the ISP, hit 'Ok'.
Leave the speed at 115200 as recommended, hit 'Ok'.
Choose Tone or Pulse dialing, hit 'Ok'.
Enter the phone number to your ISP (do not use any dashes), hit 'Ok'.
You can try to have your modem detected automatically, but it did not work for me, even on my easily detectable external modem.
If the modem wasn't detected, it will ask you for the port your modem is on. Enter the device name for your modem, hit 'Ok'.
A summary screen will appear and give you the opportunity to make changes if needed.
Choose 'Finished Write files and return to main menu.'.
Choose 'Quit Exit this utility'.

Exit the terminal window, type:

  $ exit
```

Connecting to the ISP

Log out and back in (for the group setting to take effect). Every "dialout/dip" user will now be able to connect and disconnect with these commands:

```
 $ pon    # connect to the ISP configured as "provider"
 $ poff   # disconnect the ISP configured as "provider"
```

You can also check the last messages generated by these commands with:

```
 $ plog   # shows the (status) messages generated by pon and poff
```

Comment: I am in India and I use Aircel SIM. Could you pleas tell me how do I find my ISP's phone number and my username and password?

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran , hello, ISP's phone number is generally *99# for aircel (most other service providers) in india and there is no username or password required, if you are configuring your connection using pppconfig or normally anything else, for PAP - Peer Authentication Protocol, keep username and password blank or while configuring in pppconfig press enter when it asks your username and password to jump to next step...... so simple.... isn't it.....

Comment: How to find the port that my modem is plugged into?

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran , hello. the port in which the modem is plugged is generally ttyUSB0. It can be ttyUSB1 or even ttyUSB2. There is one more method, simply install "wvdial (gnome-ppp)" , its available in ubuntu software center. after installing you can find it in your applications on your system or type "gnome-ppp" in terminal and enter. it will open "gnome-ppp". click on "setup" then in "modem tab" click on "detect" button it will detect the port modem connected to in the box if its connected. if any error comes try above steps by starting as "sudo gnome-ppp".you may use "lsusb" in terminal.